# Ошибка min() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def bestPrice(self):
    discount = []
    if self.total[0] > 1000:
        discount.append(Order.fidelity)
    if self.getCount > 5 :
        discount.append(Order.bulk_item)
    if self.countNames > 3:
        discount.append(Order.large_order)

    return min(item(self) for item in discount)
```

У меня есть класс, который содержит заказы.
Также есть разные скидки. Скидку можно только одну. Я проверяю на выполнение условий для получения разных скидок, если все норм, то добавляю в список.

А теперь нужно вернуть минимальную стоимость (то есть результат выполнения самой выгодной и доступной для конкретного заказа скидки).

Answer (score 1):

Список может быть *пустым*, когда ни одно из ваших условий не выполнено.
Потому нужен *тест на пустоту*:

```
if discount:                                     # список не пустый
    return min(item(self) for item in discount)
return None                                      # возможно пропустить - это автоматически
```

Answer (score 0):

`item` в Вашем случае, является внутренней переменной генератора, потому `self` там ни к чему. Вообще не понятно, для чего нужно создавать список из списка. Ну и соответственно нужно исключить возможность обращения к пустому списку. Можно как предложено в предыдущем ответе, можно так:

```
...
...    
return self.total[0] - self.total[0] / 100 * max(discount) \
    if discount else self.total[0]
```

Соответственно если нужно применить минимальную из возможных скидок, то используете `min(discount)`